# EmbeddedId Annotation Placement

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In a class, I have a compound/composit key. I keep getting a NullPointerException on processFKEecondPassInOrder. The error disappears after I move the @EmbeddedId annotation from the getter to the compound key declaration. I don't understand why I get the error on this case while I have used the annotation with a getter in other cases without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a problem with the AccessType of JPA, remember that there are to different places to add annotation in the JPA

```
Above fields (AccessType.FIELD)
Above getters (AccessType.PROPERTY)
```

So you probably are mixing those. Read this

http://chstath.blogspot.com/2007/05/field-access-vs-property-access-in-jpa.html